# Match two arrays in a complicated way

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have two arrays of strings.  The first array contains old data and the second array is new data that should overwrite the data in the old array.  That's easily accomplished by matching up the indexes of the two arrays and overwriting any cells that are different.

However, the issue comes when the array of new data has a different length of indexes than the old one.  For example if one new string is inserted into the middle of the new array, I don't want that index to overwrite the matching index in the old one.

Here is an example to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish...

```
myoldarray("foobar", "blah", "zilch")
mynewarray("foobar", "blah", "watcha", "zilch")
```

My output should be

```
finalarray("foobar", "blah", "watcha", "zilch")
```

The order is important, however "zilch" needs to maintain the same key as before.

Comment: Not following you here. What you like the output of this to be? The old array + 'watcha'?

Comment: What would be the result in your example?

Comment: Also, what would happen if you have `myoldarray("foobar", "blah", "zilch")` and `mynewarray("foobar", "blah", "watcha")`?

Comment: I have updated the original question with answers to these.

Answer (score 1):

have you looked array_merge() from the php manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
array_merge($myoldarray, $mynewarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you necessarily have to keep the index, for numeric arrays you can use [array_compare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to get the difference and then add it at the same position of the array. In case this index already exists, we just move the old value & index 1 key higher. I hope that's what you want to do

```
$difference = array_diff($newarr,$oldarr);
foreach($difference as $diff)
{
    foreach($newarr as $key => $value) 
    {
         if($value == $diff) 
         {
              if(array_key_exists($key,$oldarr)) 
              { 
                  $oldkey = count($oldarr)-1;
                  for($i=count($oldarr);$i>$key;$i--) 
                  {
                      $oldarr[$oldkey+1] = $oldarr[$oldkey]; 
                  }
                  $oldarr[$key] = $value;
              }
              else 
              {
                  $oldarr[$key] = $value;
              }

         }
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Doesn't array_diff return an array?  So when you try to compare $value against $diff that isn't going to work is it?  Also array_key_exists requires two parameters doesn't it?

Comment: Yes you are right, just wrote that straight out of my head. Tested it now with your example arrays and made it working :) Have fun!

Comment: That successfully put "watcha" into the right index of the old array, but I need a way for "zilch" to still have the same referenceable key as before because there is other data which expects it to be the same.  That's where I got stumped trying to do this myself - I couldn't get ordered keys to work, so I tried to use uniquely generated keys, but I need to be able to recreate the array again later on from scratch and for each index to have the same key as before.  Hopefully that made sense :P

Comment: Also I just tried new array with input as array("foobar", "baah", "baah", "watcha", "zilch");  and it appended "zilch" to the end of it several times.  To be honest I have no idea how your code is working - I think I need to sit down and have a proper think through what you are doing with it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dan... I've done a lot of thinking about my problem and I'm going to take it in a completely different direction now.